Android WebView Crashes for all URLs except `google.com`
I wanted to have a website inside android app. So I made a very simple app (from this youtube tutorial) and if I put grafanaWebsite.loadUrl("https://google.com/") into the class file, I get the google page.
If a put any other url, even https://www.google.com/" or http://google.com/ my app crashes immediately when trying to lauch it, see Logcat below. (Still didn't find any other working url.)
Ultimately, I would like to load http://192.168.xxx.xxx:3000/. What am I doing wrong ?
Thank you !
Here is AndroidManifest.xml and MainActivity.java :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.pvmonitoring">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PVMonitoring"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

package com.example.pvmonitoring;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView grafanaWebsite;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        grafanaWebsite = findViewById(R.id.grafanaWebsite);
        grafanaWebsite.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        grafanaWebsite.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        grafanaWebsite.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
    }
}

Logcat output of the crash:
2024-04-09 15:13:09.832 5963-5963/com.example.pvmonitoring E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.pvmonitoring, PID: 5963
    java.lang.SecurityException: Writable dex file '/data/data/com.example.pvmonitoring/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex' is not allowed.
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:406)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:128)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:438)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:387)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:166)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:160)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:130)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:146)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:93)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:134)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:126)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:61)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:1051)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:1143)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1428)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:3487)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:3479)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7539)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2478)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8893)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:608)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)

build.gradle (Module) :
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pvmonitoring"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}


Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash. If you do not understand what the stack trace is telling you, please edit your question and add the stack trace to it. Note that using http as a scheme is banned by default on modern versions of Android; you would need to enable cleartext traffic to support unencrypted communications like that.

Thanks, I added the stack trace but I have absolutely no idea what it is telling. And yes, I enabled cleartext traffic in the manifest if that's what you mean (but still, https://www.google.com/ is not working)

I see that in your AndroidManifest you set API 31 as the targetAPI, but can you share your build.gradle file?

build.gradle has been added. By the way, I had to replace compileSdk 32 and targetSdk 32 by compileSdk 34 and targetSdk 34 in build.gradle because I had "15 issues when checkin AAR metadata" in the begining, which solved that problem (but might make for another one ?)

What Android Studio version do you use? This error could be cause by an older AS version (the Instant Run functionality of AS may be the problem) together with a Android 14. Try to build and install your app by executing ./gradlew installDebug in AS terminal instead of using Android Studio run button and then check if the app then works when starting it via icon in Android app launcher.

Thanks @Robert, In fact I upgraded Android Studio, started new project all over again and now I don't get that error anymore !
However, the Grafana website hosted localy on a raspberry pi at home at http://192.168.xxx.xxx:3000/?orgId=1 fails to load its application files. Is it possible that it is a "non-supported" browser or that it is caused by my "reverse proxy settings" ?
Is the WebView a chromium browser ?

http is disallowed by default. You have to enable it by adding config file (and reference it in AndroidManifest.xml) and add allow cleartext traffic for your IP address see example in https://stackoverflow.com/q/53317137/150978 and https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/security-config

This error is most likely be caused by an older Android Studio version in combination with an Android 14+ device:
Android 14 devices no longer allow "executable code" like dex files to be loaded from places where the app has write access.
Android Studio contains a feature called "Instant Run" which allows to patch code updates into running apps, so if you press "Run" in Android Studio only the code changes can be uploaded instead of the whole APK file. Especially on large APK files this can save a lot of time.
It seems that older Android Studio versions write the code changes into a file like /data/data/<packagename>/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes?.dex which is no longer allowed since Android 14.
To fix this problem you have to update the used Android Studio version to at least Android Studio Hedgehog.
Alternatively if don't can or want to update Android Studio you can try to disable "Instant Run" functionality via Android Studio settings.
Or you don't use the run button and instead install your app via command-line:
./gradlew installDebug.
