HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication to **IP** not permitted by network security policy
Am trying to integrate Websocket connection from the Android Kotlin application. The Websocket connection works fine when called from the browser. But when the Android application makes WS connection I receive the below error, however other HTTP REST APIs are working fine. I had enabled android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" and network-security-config to allow clear traffic
AndroidManifest.xml
 <application       
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        tools:targetApi="31">

network_security_config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">com.abc.def</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.0.xx:9000</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>

Tried following all the solutions provided in stackoverflow.com, but nothing worked

What is definitely wrong is the part with the port :9000. Domains and IP Addresses never contain a port. Also the xx part won't work this way. I hope this was just edited for the post the keep the IP secret. Because you can't allow a whole subnet for clear text traffic, only single IPs  https://stackoverflow.com/q/53317137/150978
